# Android billing - where can I check the transactions that went through?

Tags: android

I just made a transaction go through but not sure where there is a place for developers to monitor the financial earnings.

Is there such a spot I can navigate to in my Android store admin area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote
>   I just made a transaction go through but not sure where there is a place for developers to monitor the financial earnings.

Is there such a spot I can navigate to in my Android store admin area?

Yes, the developers console.  Here's the link:

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/console.html

Later,
   --jim

Comment: PS:  I highly recommend the app Appmonger.  I can't remember if it's free or not, but if it isn't it's well worth it.